# How to include dplyr::mutate in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a single column of various characters and many rows like below:

```
> clean_AA_df

    clean_AA_fin
1              M
2              A
3              C
4              L
5              W
6              S
7              F
8              S
9              W
```

I want to add columns to this df where in each column the characters are all iteratively shifted forward one position. There is a new column for each of the 247 rows in the df.

I am able to do this one column at a time with the code below:

```
    clean_AA_df %>%
    mutate(pep_1 = dplyr::lead(clean_AA_fin, n = 0)) %>%
    mutate(pep_2 = dplyr::lead(clean_AA_fin, n = 1)) %>%
    mutate(pep_3 = dplyr::lead(clean_AA_fin, n = 2))
```

returns:

```
    clean_AA_fin pep_1 pep_2 pep_3
1              M     M     A     C
2              A     A     C     L
3              C     C     L     W
4              L     L     W     S
5              W     W     S     F
6              S     S     F     S
7              F     F     S     W
8              S     S     W     P
```

I have tried the below and variations of it, but the = sign is throwing some errors.

```
for (i in rownames(clean_AA_df)) {
  mutate(pep_[i] = dplyr::lead(clean_AA_fin, n = i))
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `!!` and `:=`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
vnames <- paste0('pep_',1:3)
values <- 0:(length(vnames)-1)
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(vnames))
{
  var <- vnames[i]
  df <- df %>% mutate(!!var:=lead(clean_AA_fin, n = values[i]))
}
```

Output:

```
  clean_AA_fin pep_1 pep_2 pep_3
1            M     M     A     C
2            A     A     C     L
3            C     C     L     W
4            L     L     W     S
5            W     W     S     F
6            S     S     F     S
7            F     F     S     W
8            S     S     W  <NA>
9            W     W  <NA>  <NA>
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(clean_AA_fin = c("M", "A", "C", "L", "W", "S", 
"F", "S", "W")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you.